# Is it possible to run multiples main and not receive the exception "Address in use: JVM_Bind"

Tags: java

I couldn't find any useful topic, unfortunately. So my problem is: I'm trying to run 2 similar web-apps via Eclipse Run configuration in 2 different work spaces. They are using different DB, ip, port but, as soon as one is running, when I try to run the other one I got this exception

> Exception in thread "main" com.ebd.hub.services.ServiceException:
> unable to start remote interface" cause by: java.net.BindException:
> Address already in use JVM_Bind

Comment: You need to deploy to a running Tomcat (assuming you deploy to a sub-path and not to the web-application root), or configure each work space to start tomcat with a different port.

Comment: The bind in this error is revering to the port of the server. Not to be confused with the other bind methods in the JVM. **Edit:** Hmm after re-reading the question it says port has already been changed. So maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: Provide more details. Is it runnable WAR bootstrapped by Spring Boot or WAR deployed into standalone Tomcat (or other app server) or something else?